# how to throw and catch error if function runs longer than n seconds

Tags: javascript, timeout

I have a function of the form:

```
async someFunction () {
  try {
    someStuff()
  } catch (err) {
    doSomeCleanup()
  }
}
```

Which gets called multiple times with workers from a queue. Now I have a new requirement that a worker should fail if it takes longer than 30 seconds to run this function with a given worker. My gut instinct was to whip up something like:

```
const timeoutCheck;
const time = new Date();
async someFunction () {
  try {
    timeoutCheck = setInterval(() => {
      if (new Date() - time > 30000) throw new Error("timeout");
    }, 2000);
    someStuff()
  } catch (err) {
    doSomeCleanup()
  } finally {
    clearInterval(timeoutCheck);
  }
}
```

But as I quickly learned the setInterval gets run outside the try/catch block so the error isn't caught inside the catch block but in the main app and the whole app crashes rather than just a worker failing. Is there a good way to contain this error in the try/catch block or another way to accomplish erroring into the try/catch block if the function runs more than 30 seconds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Promise.race()`

```js
let stop = () => new Promise((_, reject) =>
                   setTimeout(reject, 2999, "rejected"));

let fn = () => new Promise((resolve, _) =>
                 setTimeout(resolve, 3000, "resolved"));
                 
let someStuff = data => console.log(data);

let doSomeCleanup = err => console.error(err);

Promise.race([fn(), stop()])
.then(doSomeStuff, doSomeCleanup);
```

Comment: Using `async/await` `async function someFunction () {
  try {
    await Promise.race([fn(), stop()]);
  } catch (err) {
    doSomeCleanup(err)
  }
}`